# How to use Java programming to check process and port is alive or not?

Tags: java, linux, cluster-computing

I just thinking to build a cluster software in Linux in Java. I want to control the CPU load, for example, if CPU load is higher than a threshold, then I reduce execution thread sizes. I thought I could check CPU load once per second or a couple of seconds by a demon thread, how to implement it in Java? and How to implment in Java if I am going to check particular process is dead or not, and the port it opens is lost or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way (AFAIK) to do this in pure Java. You could potentially write some native C to do this and then interface using JNA / JNI (which would be the most robust solution.)

Alternatively, a quick hacky easy approach (if you're just using Linux) would be to use `Runtime.exec()` to call one of [these native](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html) approaches which you could then parse from within Java.

In terms of checking whether a process is dead or not, you could use the above approach but with `ps`.

EDIT: [This](http://bit.ly/javasysmon) may be something that helps.

Comment: Are there some C library to get CPU load and whether socket is lost?

Comment: @user84592 See my edit, there's a Java library with the C code embedded in which may do what you want.